# Woocommerce cart modifications being overwritten by checkout.js

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm hooking into Woocommerce's `woocommerce_calculate_totals` to set a minimum order amount for age verification. Basically the customer needs to have an order minimum of $1. This works on the view cart page, but the subtotal is getting overwritten by `checkout.js` - I can see it being modified after page load.

Here's my code in `functions.php`:

```
function hv_set_min_total() {
    if( is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        // set minimum cart total
        $min_cart_total = 1;

        // Total used before taxes and shipping
        $total = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;

        // compare values
        if( $total < $min_cart_total ) {
            $diff = $min_cart_total - $total;
            $woocommerce->cart->subtotal += $diff;
            $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total += $diff;
            $woocommerce->cart->subtotal_ex_tax += $diff;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'hv_set_min_total' );
```

I've also tried hooking into various other hooks that all change the subtotal, but still get overwritten by the `checkout.js` file. Any ideas on how I can stop this from happening?

Other things I've tried, but still get removed:

- Add Fee
- Negative discount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, apparently the `is_checkout()` method is returning false or not available when `checkout.js` runs, which resulted in the subtotal reverting back to its original state.

To anyone that's come across this issue: `is_checkout()` method is not available to `checkout.js`

Comment: I don't recall, it's been 2 years since this was posted and I no longer work on that project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting well but let's see if this works for you, you are using the `woocommerce_calculate_totals`, but you are not returning anything.

What I would do is:

```
function totales ($totals){
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($totals);
    //echo "</pre>";

    //All your code ...

    $totals->subtotal_ex_tax = ($totals->subtotal_ex_tax - 100000);
    $totals->cart_contents_total = ($totals->cart_contents_total - 15000);

    return $totals;

}

add_action('woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'totales', 10 , 1);
```

This way you can modify the subtotal and total but not the price of the product.

If you whant to know about the method that contains that hook [go here](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartcalculate_totals/)

Comment: Thanks, but the issue that was preventing this snippet from working was actually the `is_checkout()` method.